# How do a remove a nested document that is in an array based on _id using mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to pull a nested object off of an array of objects called createdEvents if the createdEventId equals the id I am passing to it.

#### My javascript query looks like this:

```js
db.collection("users").updateOne({ _id: userId }, { $pull: { createdEvents: { "createdEvents.createdEventId": eventId } } })
```

**I also tried the following with the same result**

```js
 const deleteUserCreatedEvent = await db.collection("users").updateOne({ _id: userId }, { $pull: { createdEvents: { "createdEventId": eventId } } })
```

my document looks like this:

```js
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63669a7fadb92eac2df57fc9"
  },
  "email": "wakywayne80@gmail.com",
  "emailVerified": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1667668607915"
    }
  },
  "createdEvents": [
    {
      "createdEventName": "pushevent",
      "createdEventDate": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1667913330000"
        }
      },
      "createdEventDescription": "It's gonnam be a good one",
      "createdEventWeights": [],
      "createdEventId": {
        "$oid": "6368222391d6001d3d2986e2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run the above code I get true returned as if the query was successful but the document is still in the database.

Answer (score 0):

### Make sure you use new ObjectId(*theIdString*) Then youdo the following query:

```js
updateOne({_id: new ObjectId(userId)}, {$pull: {createdEvents:{createdEventId:new ObjectId(eventId) }}})
```